# php parse array in object detail

Tags: php, arrays, object

I got stuck on parsing array in my php object

```
stdClass Object
(
    [result] => stdClass Object
        (
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [account] => 
                            [address] => add1
                            [category] => receive
                            [amount] => 1100
                            [label] => 
                            [vout] => 1
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [account] => 
                            [address] => add2
                            [category] => receive
                            [amount] => 11600
                            [label] => 
                            [vout] => 2
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [account] => 
                            [address] => add3
                            [category] => receive
                            [amount] => 1000
                            [label] => 
                            [vout] => 4
                        )

                )
        ) 
)
```

So how I can fetch all `details` indexes 0,1,2 etc

Comment: You can access this using `['details'][0]->account`

Comment: or with loop     `foreach($somearray['details'] as $detail)
        $detail->address` like this

Comment: $array=json_deocode(json_encode($data),true); object convert to array , anymore what do you want do it

Comment: @DhavalPurohit in my case details is an object. Is not an array. Conversion to an array gives me an empty response

Comment: You haven't mention the full array or object how can i assume?
whatever then you should try `$somobject->details[0]->account`

Comment: @DhavalPurohit Yes, I know that. I updated full object structure in question. However my question was about smart way how to parse an object `details` as inside have arrays 0,1,2 which contais an objects. I am stuck on that

Comment: `$somevar->result->details[0]->address` i think this could help you to understand.

Comment: here `$somevar =` your given example over here.

Comment: Thank you. I still will note that I know how to access objects at final point. My question was about parsing. @vivek_23 helped me. Many thanks for your time. I am  appreciate that!

Comment: Yes i have seen the answer. Keep Coding.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you could just iterate over `details` as below:

```
foreach($your_variable->result->details as $current_detail){
   echo $current_detail->account;
   // other code here
}
```

Comment: You are the best. Thank you! Saved a lot of my time. That's not my most strong side objects->array parsing. Will study that more!!!

Comment: @ArthurYakovlev Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your data is object if you converto to array u can simply do it

```
$array=json_decode(json_encode($data),true); 

print_r($array);
```

If just one details key

```
$array=json_decode(json_encode($data),true)


print_r($array['result']['details']);
```

Comment: That's gives an empty response

Comment: My question was about parsing and array in object. Look pls market answer. However keep your answer. Sometimes that's help some people. Thanks for your time :)